# How to sign string array or list of string?

Tags: java, spring-boot, signature

Generally, the sign mechanism of digital signature expects bytes to encrypt data and we can easily convert String to bytes. But if we need to sign a string array instead of a string, how could I do this?

```
            Signature sig = this.getPrivateSignature();
            sig.update(data.getBytes(UTF8));
            byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();
```

here if the data is an array of strings...what would be the standard procedure to generate a signature?

Comment: loops maybe and then you have array enc data